# Android vertical transition animation like IOS between activity/fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions

I am trying to implement a transition animation between Activity/Fragments just like default iOS animation. Is there any library or a default way to achieve this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.

After starting the new intent use [overridePendingTransition](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)). It will look something like this.

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out)
```

push_up_in.xml and push_up_out.xml have to be defined in app/src/main/res/anim/

**push_up_in**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromYDelta="100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="5000"/>
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

**push_up_out**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromYDelta="0" android:toYDelta="-100%p" android:duration="5000"/>
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="5000" />
</set>
```

Back when I wanted to change transition animations I used this resource:
https://www.mysamplecode.com/2013/02/android-animation-switching-activity.html

The animation xml files are taken from there. The animations can be changed however you like. The duration time is very long for example.  To achieve the exact same behaviour as on iOS you will need to make adjustments.

Comment: this is not the required behavior please see the animation again